# Is there a way to position the console and network panel side by side

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I'm wondering if it is possible somehow to get the console to show on the right side of the developer tools panels so that I can review console logs next to say the network panel (IE Side by side and not above/below).  This would allow me when tons of logs in console and a bunch of network requests to scroll each panel and sort of align console output with certain network calls.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.